# Finding area between curves formed by csv data

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, import, csv-format

I have a bunch of Differential Pulse Voltammetry data I am trying to import into Mathematica, and find the area between each curve and the blank. So far I have used the following commands:

```
"Data1 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-7-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]
Data2 = Import[
  "//Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-13-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]
Data3 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/HSJ-6-26-19/HSJ-6-26-19-19-#2 - \
Sheet1.csv", "Table"]
Data4 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-25-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]
Data5 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-31-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]
Data6 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-37-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]
Data7 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-43-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]
Data8 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-49-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]
Data9 = Import[
  "/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled folder/HSJ-6-26-19-55-#2 - \
Sheet1 4.47.09 PM.csv", "Table"]"

               and                                             

    "f1 = ListLinePlot[
   Import["/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/HSJ-6-26-19/HSJ-6-26-19-7-#2 - \
Sheet1.csv"]];
f2 = ListLinePlot[
   Import["/Users/chelseaswank/Desktop/untitled \
folder/HSJ-6-26-19-13-#2 - Sheet1.csv"]];
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], f1[x] - f2[x]}, {x, 0, 1.1}, 
 Filling -> {{1 -> {2}}, 3 -> Axis}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]"
```

and I get an axis and a green line. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide an example .csv file? Also, why is all of the code in quotation marks?

Comment: You may use `Interpolation` or `ListInterpolation` to turn the data into `InterpolatingFunction`s then integrate to find the area (area between can be obtained by the differences of the integrated values)

Comment: I would recommend using "CSV" over "Table".. "Table" does not use "," as a RecordSeparator by default